# Strange rare crash on certain devices relating to access anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, android

I'm seeing a really strange stack trace that happens for a small set of devices out of the total install base for my app. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Obviously stack traces are usually very helpful and point to the lines of code if not the methods that are causing crashes, but this one looks different to me. I don't quite understand this piece with all of the `or`s:

```
at com.aaronjwood.portauthority.activity.MainActivity.access$300 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .setupMac (MainActivity.java)
  at com.aaronjwood.portauthority.activity.MainActivity.access$002 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$100 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$1100 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .access$902 (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .processFinish (MainActivity.java)
  or                     .setClip (MainActivity.java)
  at com.aaronjwood.portauthority.activity.MainActivity$9.onReceive (MainActivity.java)
```

I also don't understand the anonymous classes that are part of `.access`. I'm assuming this is an Android specific thing buried somewhere in the SDK. I just don't know why it's so inconsistent.

This app is open source so you can see there's no `access` that's part of `MainActivity`: https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/blob/development/app/src/main/java/com/aaronjwood/portauthority/activity/MainActivity.java

Note that I have the deobfuscation mapping in place for this app on the developer console so the stack trace should be as accurate as possible even though proguard was used during the construction of the release APK.

Comment: Just a thought, Are u building this apk through canary version of android studio?

Comment: Nope, I'm on the latest stable version of 3.0.1

Comment: Is this exception occur in every device ?

Comment: No, from the data I've seen so far it's pretty rare and/or random. I'm not able to run into it on any of my devices like my phone and tablet. I have a few friends that say everything is fine for them with the new update as well.

Comment: Accroding to log, you are getting `NullPointerException` inside `onReceive`, may be on some devices you are getting null `intent`. Check are you getting null `intent` or not ?

Comment: That's a good point, I was looking at that area earlier but if you do a `git blame` on `MainActivity` you'll see that the code there was added > 2 years ago https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/blame/development/app/src/main/java/com/aaronjwood/portauthority/activity/MainActivity.java#L400. This crash is new since I released an update last night which makes me think there's something else going on.

Comment: Its occuring in an anonymous class used as a callback function.  We can't tell you more without code.  But at any rate, you solve it like any other NPE

Comment: I added a link to the code at the bottom of the post. If it is indeed from a callback function then what's with the `.access$<SOMENUMBER>`? I'm not getting any good indication of where the actual issue is from the stack trace. When I've run into issues in the past with callbacks or anonymous classes I'm always able to narrow it down from the stack trace that's provided. This stack trace looks all over the place to me.

Comment: @AdityaSonel I added a null check for `intent` and rolled out a quick test yesterday but I still saw the same errors coming in. I guess it's good to know for sure that it's not an issue with a null intent.

Comment: @Aaron Have you got any solution yet ?. And one more thing try to check your application on any `OnePlus` device, I know this is weird but try it.

Comment: No solution yet. I'm also seeing some crashes relating to this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972466 which people also say causes crashes in broadcast receivers when the network state changes. Hmm...

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972466#comment14 Looks like Square and Groupon apply this fix to their apps. And what do you know, I call `getResources` from a method that's called from within my broadcast receiver (https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/blob/development/app/src/main/java/com/aaronjwood/portauthority/activity/MainActivity.java#L465), which is continually `postDelayed` in a `Handler` (https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/blob/development/app/src/main/java/com/aaronjwood/portauthority/activity/MainActivity.java#L466)

Comment: I've also seen the occurrence of these crashes go down after the majority of people have installed my recent update. Adding all of this together makes it seem very similar to the reported Android bug...